# Change HTML5 data option based on URL hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following div:

```
<div id="nav-aj"  data-options='{"default":'t1","animation": {"duration": 500, "effects": "fade"}}'> </div>
```

I want to change the value of default option based on what I get from URL hash.

```
var hash = location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf('#')+1);
alert(hash);
```

For example, if the hash is A then default will be t1, else t2.

The URL structure is http://example.com/page#A or could be http://example.com/page#B

What I am stuck on is changing the value of the default.

Comment: *sigh* You beat me to rejecting that useless suggested edit, which just changed a few characters in the title and changed the part of speech of a word for no reason, without actually fixing anything...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function updateDiv(hash) {
    var $div = $('#nav-aj');
    var options = $div.data('options');
    switch (hash) {
        case 'A':
            options['default'] = 't1';
            break;
        case 'B':
            options['default'] = 't2';
            break;
        default:
            option['default'] = 't1';
    }
    $div.attr('data-options', options);
}

$(function () {

    var hash = window.location.hash.split('#')[1]
    updateDiv(hash);

    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        updateDiv(window.location.hash.split('#')[1]);
    });

});
```

Also, use this since you have a bad quote in your data-options:

```
<div id="nav-aj" data-options='{"default":"t1","animation": {"duration": 500, "effects": "fade"}}'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<!-- added `""` around `t1` -->
<div id="nav-aj"  data-options='{"default":"t1","animation": {"duration": 500, "effects": "fade"}}'> </div>
```

js

```
var url = window.location.href
, hash = url.split("#")[1] === "A" ? "t1" : "t2";
  $("#nav-aj").data("options").default = hash;
```

```js
var url = "http://example.com/page#B"
, hash = url.split("#")[1] === "A" ? "t1" : "t2";

  $("#nav-aj").data("options").default = hash;
console.log(hash, $("#nav-aj").data("options").default);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-aj"  data-options='{"default":"t1","animation": {"duration": 500, "effects": "fade"}}'> </div>
```